# Google App engine + Spring = slow startup?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I read that Google App Engine (GAE) will shut down your application if it goes idle, and startup/boot everything again when it gets a request. And i know that Spring startup is slow, like 2-3 seconds even for a small web app. Is working on GAE using Spring really suffer from this badly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on your requirements for response time.  There are ways in App Engine to have a "permanent" instance and "warmup" instances.  This will minimize your response times.

Comment: I have few Spring apps on GAE, big and small. For big app, with hundreds of beans, i'm using F2 instances. Others starts quickly enough under default F1

Comment: I recommend this [Google I/O talk by Matt Stephenson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFarE1hH0ss). It discusses how App Engine differs from old fashioned server environments, what that entails, and what patterns you should be aware of.

Comment: [Optimizing Spring Framework for App Engine Applications](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really not that bad but considering your instances are being shutdown and started constantly, you should work on getting your startup as fast as possible. A few pointers to consider:

1. Enable [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_Warmup_requests)
2. Enable [resident instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)
3. Optimize Spring config (There are great suggestions in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization))

Comment: Um, another question, let's say i want an instant start Java web app within GAE, which Java framework that you recommend? Fully compatible out of the box will be better. I read that Play and Grails need lots of workaround to be compatible with GAE...

Comment: Well there is very little that will work on GAE out of the box due to the restrictions on filesystem and threading. If you're planning to use complex  frameworks such as Play or grails I suggest you set you app using a managed VM to skip those limitations.